# Calculated fields that improve performance but need to be maintained (EF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have this "1 to N" model:

```
class Reception
{
    public int ReceptionId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ReceptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Reception Reception { get; set; }
}
```

And this action, `api/receptions/list`

```
public JsonResult List() 
{
     return dbContext.Receptions
        .Select(e => new 
         {
             code = e.Code,
             itemsCount = e.Items.Count,
             quantity = e.Items.Sum(i => i.Quantity)

         }).ToList();
}
```

which returns a list of receptions, with their number of items:

```
[
    {code:"1231",itemsCount:10,quantity:30},
    {code:"1232",itemsCount:5,quantity:70},
    {code:"1234",itemsCount:30,quantity:600},
    ...
]
```

This was working fine but I'm having too many `Reception`'s and `Item`'s thus the query is taking too long...

So I want to speed up by adding some persisted fields to `Reception`:

```
class Reception
{
    public int ReceptionId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int ItemsCount { get; set; } // Persisted
    public int Quantity { get; set; } // Persisted
}
```

With this change, the query ends up being this:

```
public JsonResult List() 
{
     return dbContext.Receptions
        .Select(e => new 
         {
             code = e.Code,
             itemsCount = e.ItemsCount,
             quantity = e.Quantity

         }).ToList();
}
```

My question is:
What's the best way to maintain these two fields? 
I will gain in performance but now I will need to be more careful with the creation of `Item`'s

Today an `Item` can be created, edited and deleted:

- `api/items/create?receptionId=...`
- `api/items/edit?itemId=...`
- `api/items/delete?itemId=...`

I also have a tool for importing receptions via Excel:

- `api/items/createBulk?...`

Maybe tomorrow I will have more ways of creating `Item`'s, so the question is how do I make sure that these two new fields, `ItemsCount` and `Quantity` will be up to date always?

Should I create a method within `Reception` like this?

```
class Reception
{
    ...

    public void UpdateMaintainedFields() 
    {
        this.Quantity = this.Items.Sum(e => e.Quantity);
        this.ItemsCount = this.Items.Count();
    }
}
```

And then REMEMBER to call it from all the previous URL's? (`items/create`, `items/edit`, ...)

Or maybe should I have a stored procedure in the database?

What is the common practice? I know there are `calculated columns` but these refer to fields of the same class. Also there are `indexed views`, but I'm not sure if they apply well to scenarios like this.

Comment: You might want to look at the queries that EF is generating and seeing what the query plan it is doing for those queries is. You might be able to keep using your current method but you just need to add the proper index or two.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking that this would not be performant. Have you looked at SQL profiler? Do you happen to be issuing multiple queries? And how does this possibly compile? A list can't be wrangled to an ActionResult....

Comment: The current method is already well indexed (there is an index for column `ReceptionId`, table `Items`)

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems to me that you do not have a layer for business logic, and everything is implemented in the controllers, this causes the problem for you that when you would have a different way (and it seems, that you mean a different controller) you have to implement this logic again and it is easy to forget, and if you do not forget, you could forget to maintain later.

So I would recommend to have a layer for business logic (like adding new items) and use it from the controllers where you want to create items.

I would also recommend write the function UpdateMaintainedFields as you asked, but call it in the business logic layer after adding the items, not in the controllers!

You could write the logic on the database also (trigger) if you can accept that you can't write unit test.

Comment: Today all of my controllers have access to the `dbContext` object. This means that they can read (eg. `dbContext.Items.Where...`) and write (eg. `dbContext.Items.Add(...)`). So your suggestion is that I remove `dbContext` from all of my controllers and instead I add them something like a `businessLogic` instance

Comment: @sports Yes, something similar. You could create a different project in the solution and refer it from the web project. Create a class "ItemService", that would contain all the logic related to creating/updating/deleting... Item entities. In ItemService inject dbContext by constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original query cannot be improved with the correct execution plan in SQLServer, the way to update these fields is via a trigger in the DB. When an insert occurs (or possible an update if your persisted fields change according to the data) then when an insert occurs to that table, the trigger is run. It would be responsible for updating all the rows with the new values.

Obviously your insert performance would drop, but your query performance would be that of a simple index and read of a single row. Obviously you wouldn't be able to use this trick if you were to return a subset of the table, as all the quantities would be fixed.

An alternative is to hold the count and quantity sums in a separate table, or in a dummy row that holds the summed quantities as its entry for quantity. YMMV.

---

PS I hate how what is a SQL question has been turned in one about C# code! Learn SQL and run the queries you need directly in the DB, that will show you much more about the performance and structure of what you're looking for than getting EF involved. /rant :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the same information duplicitly, which can lead to inconsistencies. As an inspiration, indexes are also duplicating data. How do you update them? You don't. It is all fully transparent. And I would recommend the same approach here.

Make sum table, maintained by triggers. The table would not be included in any datacontext schema, only way to read it would be through non updateable views or stored procedures. Its name should evoke, that nobody should ever touch this table directly.

You can now access your data from various frameworks and do not worry about updating anything. Database would assure the precalculated sums are always correct, as long as you do not write to the sum table on your own. In fact you can add or remove this table any time and no application would even notice.